# Unable to update xml from WPF UI

Tags: .net, xml, wpf, xml-parsing

From a WPF UI I am adding a string message to create this xml structure

Expected output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<requests> 
   <request>123</request>
   <request> 
      <request>123Texttbox value</request>
   </request>
</requests>
```

UI:

```xml
<Button 
    Content="Save" 
    Command="{Binding AddRequest}"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="336,224,0,212" />
```

MainViewModel:

```cs
public RelayCommand AddRequest
{
    get
    {
        return _addRequest ?? (_addRequest = new RelayCommand(parm => DataService.AddRequest("123Texttbox value")));
    }
}
```

Add Method:

```cs
public void AddRequest(string message)
{
    string file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLFileFullName"];
    var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
    var ele = new XElement("request", message.Substring(1, 3));  // create the ID node
    doc.Root.Add(ele);
    var xElement = doc.Root.Element("request");  // create the request under ID node
    if (xElement != null) xElement.Add(message);
    doc.Save(file);
}
```

xml: after running the program

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<requests>

</requests>
```

but after executing the program the xml file is not populated with data. am I missing somthing? thanks

**UPDATE**

```
string file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLFileFullName"];
        var doc = XDocument.Load(file);

        //  new XElement("ID", message.Substring(0, 3)),

        doc.Root.Add(
            new XElement("Request",
                new XElement("ID", message.Substring(0, 3)),
                new XElement("Message", message))
            );



        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLFileFullName"] = doc.ToString();
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("XMLFileFullName");
```

Comment: You're question is kind of confusing to understand. I can't tell the different between what you are getting as a result right now and what is expected.  I also don't know what kind of process you have going on in AddMethod, but I would suggest to read [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341343.aspx) documentation and make sure to read the examples.

Comment: @NETscape I updated my question I hope its clear now. tnx

Comment: What do you start with in the file (XMLFileFullName)? Everything in the last section of XML?

Comment: @NETscape this is what I start with                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<requests>

</requests>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your code in LinqPad to see what the output was, and it was not valid.  This is what it looked like:

[image]

Another thing that is missing is you're not understand that calling `doc.Save(file)` isn't going to save your application settings.  Instead, you will want to actually set the value of the new application settings and then save them using the configuration manager.  I was able to write the following working code.  You need to comment out my `file` variable and uncomment your `file` variable.

```
string message = "123Texttbox value";
string file = Properties.Settings.Default.XMLFileFullName;
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);

doc.Root.Add(
    new XElement("request", message.Substring(0, 3)),
    new XElement("request", 
        new XElement("request", message)
    )
);
var xElement = doc.Root.Element("request");  // create the request under ID node

//if (xElement != null) xElement.Add(ele);

Properties.Settings.Default.XMLFileFullName = doc.ToString();
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

If you run this code, you should see the changes affect the application settings.  This is what my results were:

[image]

On another note, I do think your XML structure is flawed.   I'm not sure why calling the `AddRequest` function would add two request items, but that is a different topic of discussion.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Use application properties instead. Use [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c482f6f5-3ccd-4a7b-94ab-f974a1a9b8bf/how-to-saveupdate-appsetting-keyvalue-pair-in-local-config-file?forum=csharpgeneral) link to get yourself started off.  I updated the code in the code snippet above.

Make sure you are able to understand the difference between setting the Property to User vs. Application scope.

Comment: the code is not compiling, it fails at ConfigurationManager.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); It is not able to call .Save from ConfigurationManager

Comment: I replace it with this but still not saving the change                           var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLFileFullName"] = doc.ToString();
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("XMLFileFullName");